# explode a dictionary to different rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-analysis

This is how my original dataset looks like:

```
url         boolean          details                                             
                                                                                       numberOfPages       date
xzy.com     0                {'https://www.eltako.depdf': {'numberOfPages': 440, 'date': '2017-09-20'},'https://new.com': {'numberOfPages': 240, 'date': '2017-09-20'} }
```

The numberOfPages and date col is initally empty while the `details` col has a dictionary. I want to iterate through all rows (urls) and check their `details` column. For each key in the details column, I want to make a separate row and then use the numberOfPages and date values to add column values. The result should be something like this:

```
url         boolean          pdfLink                             numberOfPages   date           
xzy.com     0                https://www.eltako.depdf            440             2017-09-20
                             https://new.com                     240             2017-09-20
```

I tried this but the second line gives me an error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

```
def arrange(df):
    
    df=df.explode('details').reset_index(drop=True)
    out=pd.DataFrame(df['details'].map(lambda x:[x[y] for y in x]).explode().tolist())
```

The original type of `Info` col was dict. I also tried changing the type to str but I still got the same error. Then I tried changing the lambda function to this:

```
lambda x:[y for y in x]
```

but the output I get is something like this:

```
url         boolean          details                             0    
xzy.com     0                https://www.eltako.depdf            h
Nan         Nan                                                  t
                                                                 t
                                                                 p
```

So basically the character of the link are being exploded into different rows. How can I fix this?

---

```
{'Company URL': {0: 'https://www.eltako.de/'},
 'Potential Client': {0: 1},
 'PDF Link': {0: nan},
 'Number of Pages': {0: nan},
 'Creation Date': {0: nan},
 'Info': {0: {'https://www.eltako.de/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Eltako_Gesamtkatalog_LowRes.pdf': {'numberOfPages': 440,
    'date': '2017-09-20'}}},1: {'https:new.com: {'numberOfPages': 230,
    'date': '2017-09-20'}}}}
```

Comment: In what form the original data comes? Could so happen that it would be easier to parse before DF construction (say, with `pd.json_normalize`)

Comment: I was returning a dictionary from a function and appending it ```df = df.append({"Info":pdfLinks}``` like this. However, when I checked the df, the value appeared in square brackets, like a list. So I changed the above appending to ```"Info":dict.fromkeys(pdfLinks)```  So then its a dict. Where could I use the normalization @crayxt

Comment: Can you post `df.head().to_dict()` so we are able to reconstruct the sample df?

Comment: can you see the updated qs? @crayxt